# Displaying Hidden Javascript Divs if Java Enabled without Duplicate content

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, hidden

In short, I am trying to have an HREF menu with Javascript functions to display DIVs. However, my concern is that while I could have two seperate DIVs, one with Javascript if enabled, and one with No JAvascript enabled, I do not want to duplicate raw content on my page (as spiders will index Display: none html)

I am not familiar with functions of javascript, and best practices. My instinct is to string replace the DIVs for a specific id style tags when javascript is present..

Ie, logic that if javascript enabled, then replace text of style tags to to display=none (for specific ID's)

Also - is there a way to be nonspecific with javascript. Such as if i have contentid1,contentid2,contentid3,contentid4,contentid5,contentid6 I could use, via regular expression or equivalent for contentid 2-6

I will use this on multiple pages where contentids change. I do not know if i should create a javascript conditional style, as I am not sure how that style would be applied for multiple IDs  (seen here) 
[Hide html only when Javascript is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258215/hide-html-only-when-javascript-is-available)

Heres my current code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function showHide(d)
{
var onediv = document.getElementById(d);
var divs=['content1','content2','content3','content4'];
for (var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
  {
  if (onediv != document.getElementById(divs[i]))
    {
    document.getElementById(divs[i]).style.display='none';
    }
  }
onediv.style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

then here is my menu

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content1');">link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content2');">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content3');">link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:showHide('content4');">link4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then here is my content (note, i leave the content1 div visible by default

```
<div id="content1" >Content</div>
<div id="content2" style="display: none;">Stuff</div>
<div id="content3" style="display: none;">Things</div>`
```

I would like to avoid flickering if possible, and page refreshing if possible. Like could there be a condition so that content2+ have inlinestyle changed to hidden. If no javascript, my paeg just becomes really, really long.
?

Sorry-rambling. Tired, and have pneumonia :)

Comment: Also - this is on a wordpress site. I have access to the theme functions, so I could try php, but I am not good with partial str_replacing

Comment: Also - Can I pay someone $10 for a detailed answer? Or is that against stack overflow community standards?

Comment: I think it's a little against the guidelines (but you can always hire a freelancer, well, not for something as simple as this). Basically, you either print out the divs without `display:none` and hide them with JS (this way they won't be hidden when JS is disabled) or give your divs a class and put a style tag inside a `<noscript>` with `display: block !important;` to ensure that they will be visible when JS is disabled.

Comment: Fabio - cant give you an answer - but thank you. Your comment is very helpful

Comment: Stupid css question -  iwould need to have custom css style loaded into main stylesheet, then have the noscript tag at bottom of header, correct?